# How to get the data associated with a checkbox in Django views

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-4

I have a database that I'm trying to access via a template in Django.  I'd like to be able to select some checkboxes and have it return the items associated with those checkboxes in my views.py so I can perform some logic on that data.

`template.py`

```
<input type="checkbox" checked autocomplete="off" name="tag" value={{ recipe.id }} />{{ recipe }}
```

`views.py`

```
def create_list(request):
    check_values = request.POST.getlist('tag')
    context = {'check_values': check_values)
    return render(request, 'grocery_lists/create_list.html', context)
```

The create_list.html page simply displays {{ check_values }}.  This was my attempt at a troubleshooting step so I could see what was stored in the variable `check_values`, However, `check_values` ends up being an empty list.  I'm having trouble finding a solution that fits my use case.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is the checkbox wrapped in a form element? I'm assuming if you print request.POST from create_list you're not seeing your checkbox?

Comment: the checkbox is not wrapped in a form element...  The checkbox exists, and I'm able to click on the items I need. However, its like the information is not being relayed to my views.py.  Create_list is just an empty list after I move to the next page.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment - the checkbox value isn't making it to your view because it is not in a form. Wrap it in a form with method="POST" and action="{% url 'create_list' %}" and have a submit button submit that form - and then you should see it. Something like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'create_list' %}">
    <input type="checkbox" checked autocomplete="off" name="tag" value={{ recipe.id }} />{{ recipe }}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I'd also add that forms in Django are probably worth checking out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/

Django can handle rendering forms for you automatically based on models.

Comment: Thank you for the advice.  I don't actually need 'check_values' on the next page, I was just using that to see what the output was, as I am still trying to figure Django out.  I need to be able to take that list in 'check_values' and run some logic on it before it gets to the next page.  Based on your reply, it looks like the 'action' attribute might get me there? Or is it just that I'm missing the "POST" method (which i don't have)?

Comment: I thought that you said your checkbox is not in a form element?

Comment: If you do have a form element already there then yeah you'll need to add method="POST", method defaults to GET, and you can not post form data with GET, only send querystrings in the URL